# tb_event_death when single stepping in dbx

Tags: c++, multithreading, debugging, solaris, dbx

When I am single stepping through one thread of a multi threaded program, the debugger gets interrupted with:

```
0x(some hex ref) : tdb_event_death      : ret
dbx: thread has exited -- next aborted
```

My guess is a thread somewhere in the program I am debugging has stopped, but it's not the one I'm debugging so I can't see why I have to restart the debugging process to continue.

I have a work around,  I set a breakpoint on the next line then rerun, which works but is very annoying, it is really slowing down my debugging. Does anyone know a better way ?  (single step ALL threads for example)

Answer (score 1):

try setting you environment variable _THREAD_ERROR_DETECTION to 0

[some light reading](http://blogs.oracle.com/quenelle/entry/debugging_tips_for_threaded_programs)

Comment: This does work.  I would accept it, but its too late... (sorry)

Answer (score 1):

What is likely happening is that some other thread has exited (doing `next` resumes all threads in the process, not just the one you are debugging). You can verify this: do `thread` when you start debugging a particular place, and again when you get the `next aborted` message.

If the thread you are debugging doesn't need to interact with other threads, you can resume just that one thread with `next <thread_id>` (where `thread_id` is the one `thread` command prints).

A word of caution: if your thread needs to malloc() some memory, you may have to resume other threads, because one of them could be holding e.g. `malloc` lock.